# stand-alone NT service using RAD studio2010 / Oracle

Tags: delphi, c++builder, dbexpress

Is it possible to deploy a stand-alone dbexpress NT service  using RAD Studio 2010 with Oracle as the database?

Answer (score 0):

DBExpress uses external drivers for its database access.  You would have to deploy the Oracle DBX driver with your service.  You cannot compile it directly into the service executable (unless you place it in the executable's resources and then extract it at runtime before using DBX).